# Move marker/labels within area to avoid clashes with clusters in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I've trying to display point data and areas with labels using Leaflet. The point data is in a markerClusterGroup and the points pop in and out of clusters according to zoom. Also on the map are large areas representing national parks and each park has a marker currently drawn using the GeoJson's centre property. At some zoom levels the pins drawn for the point data have labels which stick out to the side and clash with the area shape labels. I'd like to be able to assign the area shape label to the area and have Leaflet draw it anywhere within that shape that doesn't clash with a point data marker. This would also mean that if the user zoomed in far enough that some of the national park area was not visible, the label would still be shown rather than attached to a specific location within the area which might be off screen.

Is this possible?

Comment: Where are these labels coming from?  I'm a little confused as to the components involved here.  There are markers that are clustered, that have popups, and there are GeoJSON shapes with labels, and you want their placement not to conflict?  Perhaps a sandbox showing your issue would help

Comment: @SethLutske There are markers with text labels (and if clicked they show popups). There are areas (national parks) that need to be labelled. I'm trying to get the labels for the area and the labels for the points to avoid each other. As far as I can see there is no way of labelling an area and having Leaflet intelligently workout where on screen that label should be.